# Why some ioc frameworks are so complex?because just a few line of code seems can do this too

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

The ioc frameworks I mentioned are Unity, Autofac, structuremap and so on.

The code is:

```
public class Ioc
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Type> mapper = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

    public static T CreateInstance<T>()
    {
        var t = typeof (T);
        if (mapper.ContainsKey(t))
        {
            return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(mapper[t]);
        }
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }

    public static void Map<TInterface, TImplementation>() where TImplementation : TInterface
    {
        var inferfaceType = typeof (TInterface);
        var implementationType = typeof (TImplementation);
        if (mapper.ContainsKey(inferfaceType))
        {
            mapper[inferfaceType] = implementationType;
        }
        else
        {
            mapper.Add(inferfaceType, implementationType);
        }
    }
}
```

And it can be used like this:

```
Ioc.Map<IUserService, UserService>();
Ioc.Map<IUserBusiness, UserBusiness>();
```

and

```
var userService = Ioc.CreateInstance<IUserService>()
```

It is used just like the way the ioc frameworks are used.

Is there a big performance difference between them?

Comment: How does your solution handle cases where `UserService` requires `UserBusiness`.  How does your solution handle cases where `UserService` should be a singleton but `UserBusiness` should be per-request (e.g. web application).  How does your service scale in cases where I have multiple services in a single assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not there is a 'big difference' in performance is completely depending on context. The question is: is it fast enough in your case and does this solve all your needs?

Take a look at [this very interesting comparison between different DI libraries for .NET](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison). It compares performance between [the major 8](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/conforming-container/) libraries and many other small ones.

But besides performance, there are many other features that you should be aware of that might help you a lot. Some libraries for instance (Castle Windsor and Simple Injector) contain 'Diagnostic Services' that help you find possible misconfigurations that are otherwise very hard to detect (such as [captive dependencies](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/) and many others). And Simple Injector for instance follows a very strict [design principles](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/2.6/principles.html) that tries to minimize the configuration errors you can make as a user.

Other features that make the internal implementation of a DI library much more complex are features such as lifestyle management, auto-wiring, cyclic dependency detection, resolving collections, resolving generic types. And don't forget the integration with all kinds of different frameworks and technologies.

So in general, I don't advice to use your own mini DI library. Either you use one of the existing DI libraries out there, or you don't use a container at all. Do note that don't using a DI library is not the same as not using the Dependency Injection pattern! You should absolutely apply Dependency Injection, but [whether or not a DI library is beneficial](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) for your application is dependent on the size of your application. If the application is small, it is not a shame to hand-wire all object graphs manually in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). As a benefit you get compile-time support for free.